# Stroller ball bearing grease

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work

On Yom Tov, when we push a stroller, the grease in the ball bearings holding the wheels to the axle, gets smeared within the balls. Is this is a melacha of smearing?

Comment: Isn’t it already smeared from before? It’s just there as a buffer to make it roll easier. It doesn’t get resmeared, it is already there and just stays there more or less. Maybe it gets moved but it’s not smeared more than it was from before

Comment: I'd guess that it doesn't fall under that melacha because there is no material change from the start to the end - it just swaps around positions.  I think the melacha is more about having a big blob and spreading it out over a surface, but I'm not certain.  It probably also helps that your intent is just to move the buggy and the grease being spread around only happens as a by-product of that.

Comment: @MosesSupposes Ty 4 ur reply. So isn't nivea cream on my hands also just swaps around positions? Not being a wise guy; just trying to understand the halacha TY! Chag Sameach!!

Comment: If you've spread it on before Shabbos/Yom Tov, yes, I would think that is ok